# Which pairings of variables following the Fisher exact test are significant?

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, fishers-exact-test

I have a 11*13 contingency table with mostly low/zero counts so I ran the Fisher's exact test to determine significance or not. Now that I have done that, is there any way which I can see which pairs are significant?

Thanks

(Btw I am using R but explanation in MiniTab or Excel would be fine if that is only way)

Comment: There is a related question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775435/post-hoc-pairwise-fisher-exact-test. Adapting the example given will provide pairwise comparisons.